# What is special about the dummy interface dummy0?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian

I'm creating dummy interfaces to set up dynamic routing, which all works fine. But I found one curious detail I can't explain: For some reason, when creating a dummy interface with the name `dummy0`, I get an error message, even though the interface is created correctly and works, while when using another name, no error message is shown:

```
root@sdsdd:~# ip link
[lo and eth0 not shown]
root@sdsdd:~# ip link add dummy0 type dummy
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
root@sdsdd:~# ip link add dummy1 type dummy
root@sdsdd:~# ip link
[lo and eth0 not shown]
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether c6:9c:73:8b:17:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: dummy1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether be:50:5b:53:99:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What gives? What makes the name `dummy0` special? I could not find any mention of it anywhere in `/etc/network/interfaces*`. I tried this on Debian 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually really simple. When running `ip link add dummy1 type dummy`, `ip` will automatically load the `dummy` kernel module (it did not do that in earlier versions). That module has a parameter `numdummies`, which configures how many dummy devices to create automatically and [which defaults to 1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2/drivers/net/dummy.c#L39).

Thus, loading the module already creates a `dummy0` network interface without `ip` knowing. `ip` then tries to create another interface with the same name, which fails with the error message `File exists`.